# how to update a histogram in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, histogram

I have a histogram that I want to update as I move a Scale to scroll through a csv file.  The Each line in the cvs file is 2 peaks and I want the histogram log the height of each peak and  update every time I move the slider.  To update a plot I used `.set_xdata` and `.set_ydata`.  Is there a similar set for a histogram?

Comment: Matplotlib's solution to your problem is to draw custom rectangles instead of using the pylab hist. Have a look at this example on their website http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/histogram.html

Comment: when I from matplotlib import animation, I get the error "no module named animate". I'm using python(x,y) which is using python 2.6.6

Comment: Looks like animate was added to matplotlib v1.1 and I'm using 1.0.1. fudge

Comment: You might also look at using `step` which will give you (in my opinion) a better looking histogram anyway.

Comment: also, the only thing that `animation` is being used for there is the timers and such, everything else should work for you.